# What is the equivalent of normalize-space() of XSLT in MS-SQL server?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

What is equivalent of [`normalize-space()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms256063.aspx) of XSLT in MS-SQL server?
If there isn't a built-in function, then how to implement this function in an SQL Query?

Answer (score 1):

There is no built in function that I know of. Building one yourself could look like this.

```
create function NormalizeSpace(@S nvarchar(max)) returns nvarchar(max)
as
begin
  set @S = replace(@S, nchar(9), N' ')
  set @S = replace(@S, nchar(10), N' ')
  set @S = replace(@S, nchar(13), N' ')

  while charindex(N'  ', @S) > 0
  begin
    set @S = replace(@S, N'  ', N' ')
  end  
  return rtrim(ltrim(@S))
end
```

**Update:**

Have a look at this article by [Jeff Moden](https://stackoverflow.com/users/313265/jeff-moden) for a faster way (no while loop) to do this:
[REPLACE Multiple Spaces with One](http://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/T-SQL/68378/)

```
create function NormalizeSpace(@S nvarchar(max)) returns nvarchar(max)
as
begin
  set @S = replace(@S, nchar(9), N' ')
  set @S = replace(@S, nchar(10), N' ')
  set @S = replace(@S, nchar(13), N' ')

  set @S = replace(@S, N'  ', N' '+nchar(7))
  set @S = replace(@S, nchar(7)+N' ', N'')
  set @S = replace(@S, nchar(7), N'')

  return rtrim(ltrim(@S))
end
```